Using a form to update data in a table connected to a SELECT DISTINCT sub query
I'm making a form in Access that is based on a query. Users should be able to enter/edit data in 2 fields via the form. The problem is that I need to use DISTINCT to clean up the list that users see.
DISTINCT was applied to a Make-Table sub query and the resultant temp table was then connected to the table with the data that needs editing (in the query that the form is connected to).
I'm new to this and was thrilled that things were working until I realized that the list shown in the form would not update unless I manually triggered the Make-Table sub query. Then I realized that even that didn't update it for other users. Dead end!
Please tell me there's a way to do this. What would you recommend?

It fun and easy to bind your forms to queries to help you find and select information. Your bound form should be a subform. Once you find what you want to edit, handle the editing and update via unbound controls on the main unbound form. Selecting a record from your bound form (in datasheet view) should populate unbound controls the user can edit. Then provide a save button that runs an update query.

Thank you for making it sound attainable, Bart. Can you to dumb that down for me or point me towards a resource with more detail?

The northwind database  should have examples you can follow. If you have no VBA coding experience it might be difficult. To start make a new blank form named main. add unbound controls for editing , 1 label for the mode with "Edit Mode" as the caption, and 4 buttons (Add mode, Edit mode, Save, Clear). Add a subform control. specify your current form as its source object. Set the subform's default view to datasheet.  Code subform current record click event to populate your main form. Save button will need to construct and execute an update command using text from the unbound controls.

Why would you need to edit a DISTINCT dataset? Makes me think something very wrong with data schema. Could post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.
